# In case of one to one relationship CascadeType.ALL gives Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

In `spring-data-jpa` using a `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` I got an error.

`Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction`

How solve it without changing cascadeType?

Entity code of Student

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private WorkSiteEducation workSiteEducation;
```

Entity code of workSiteEducation

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private Student student;
```

code to save it : -

```
 public StudentDTO saveStudent(StudentDTO studentDTO) throws StudentServiceException {
    Student student = beanMapperUtil.createEntityFromDto(studentDTO, Student.class);
    System.out.println(student);
    if (pqssValidationUtil.validate(student)) {
        logger.logEvent(MessageConstant.METHOD_ADD_STUDENT, "Saving Student");
        student = studentDomain.saveStudent(student);
        studentDTO = beanMapperUtil.createDtoFromEntity(student, StudentDTO.class);
    } else {
        throw new StudentServiceException(pqssValidationUtil.getErrorMessages());
    }
    return studentDTO;   
}
```

Comment: First of all, by giving us a little more info on your entities, and how you persist/merge them

Comment: I update it and at domain layer, it's simple save method of JPARepository.

Comment: I believe there will be more error logs. Please check

Comment: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Comment: Can you post the complete exception stacktrace?